# iOS 6+ Facebook / Twitter share - pre-populate text or not

Tags: facebook, text, ios6, share

I have been getting into iOS 6 and its Share functionality.  I see that some people (e.g. apple in their app store), pre-populate the Facebook share pop-up with some relevant text, while others leave this empty for users to fill (providing only the image/url).

I see the benefits with the former (since you can save users time) e.g. by posting: "Loving this new app".  But equally, if this section is left blank then users are more likely to create a personalised message.

Does anyone know the best practise?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it looks like the iTunes App Store does pre-populate these fields with the app name and developer name.

However just had this pointed out to me by a colleague at work:
The relevant part of Facebook's platform policy is section IV. 2 here:
https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#integration

Guess the jury is still out?